# Putting a port in a remote server SSH tunneling

Tags: ssh, tunneling

I need to know if is possible to put a local port in a remote machine via ssh tunneling

Example

```
Machine A: port 80 
Machine B: Nothing
```

Inside Machine A (**important, because A can see B, but B can't see A**)

```
A>  ssh -f -N -? 80:B:8585 user@B
```

result

```
Machine A: port 80 
Machine B: port 8585 (really A:80)
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: It seems to me that you've just defined SSH tunnelling itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the `-R` switch

```
ssh -f -N -R 8585:localhost:80 user@B
```

`localhost` is from A's perspective, so it means to forward port 8585 on B to port 80 on A.

See also the `RemoteForward` setting in your `~/.ssh/config`.